# implementing recursive function in MIPS

Tags: recursion, mips

I'm a bit confused on how to compile recursive functions in mips:
the following question was in a previous exam in my computer organization course: 
the question asks us to compile:

```c
int sum(int n){
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n + sum( sum(n-1) – sum(n-2) );
}
```

My attempt at tackling this problem:

```
sum: bgt $a0, 1, sum_recursive
add $v0, $0,1
jr $ra


sum_recursive: sub $sp, $sp, -12
sw $ra ,0($sp)     # storing the return address
sw $a0, 4($sp)     # storing the argument n

addi $a0, $a0, -1  # n-1
jal sum
sw $v0, 8($sp)     # the return value of sum(n-1)
lw $a0, 4($sp)     # a0=n

addi $a0, $a0, -2  # a0=n-2
jal sum
lw $t0, 8($sp)     # the return value of sum (n-1)
sub $v0, $t0, $v0  # sum(n-1) - sum (n-2)
lw $a0, 4($sp)     

add $a0, $v0, $0  # a0=sum (n-1)-sum (n-2)
jal sum
lw $a0, 4($sp)     
add $v0, $v0, $a0 # $v0 = n+ sum (sum (n-1)- sum(n-2))
lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $a0, 4 ($sp)
add $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra
```

Thank you

Comment: 1) You haven't mentioned what the problem with your current code is. 2) The proper instruction for jumping to a function is `jal`, not `j`.

Comment: I'm asking if the code I wrote is the correct way to compile the function. and thanks I just noticed about jal

Comment: Run it and find out if it's correct